# Ruby gem to automatically add a comment at the top of each view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Is there a gem I read about recently that adds a comment in HTML automatically at the beginning of each view?

I think I read about this gem somewhere. Is it compatible with Rails 2 and 3?

Comment: I remember reading about this too... but I sure can't find anything right now....

Answer (score 0):

I still don't see what I thought I saw before, but maybe these would help:

http://www.railslodge.com/search/plugin?commit=Search&query=partial